# react-router-dom v6.4 not rendering components

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I know there's a ton of similar questions like this but I'm super stumped and I simply cannot get this to work. If I code the component Home in the return like this, my page renders fine:

App.jsx

```
import './App.css';
import Home from './pages/Home.jsx'

function App() {
  return (
    <Home />
  );
}

export default App;
```

But when I move it into the router structure it will not load no matter what I've tried

App.jsx

```
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './pages/Home.jsx'

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Home.jsx

```
function Home() {
    return (
      <div style={{ padding: 20 }}>
        <h2>Home View</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adip.</p>
      </div>
    );
  }

  export default Home;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App.jsx';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console ?

Comment: I don't see any overt issues with the code. Are there any errors or warnings in the console? How are you running the app?

Comment: Add your index.js you might be missing something

Comment: ok added index.js, i have no console errors

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your app.js. please try this one:

```
import './App.css';
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from './pages/Home.jsx'

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
     <Routes> // your problem occure here
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
     </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: How is that different from the code in the Q lol ?

Comment: you use the parent route then routes try this one if not work then inform me. without using it you can not say lol!!

Comment: sorry if it hurts ... I couldn't get your point though

Comment: Other than not renaming the `BrowserRouter` import how is this any different than the OP's code? What is the issue you think this resolves? What is the explanation?

Comment: Yes this tbh ...

Comment: Ok i did try your sample but didnt see any change. is there any other info i can provide that would help us narrow it down? I just installed v6.4.0 yesterday so I've never actually gotten it to work before. any setup I can check? The json file does show a dependency

Answer (score 0):

Well I dont know exact what was causing the error unfortunately, but I restarted a new app (this was just a test app anyway) and everything worked properly. I also reinstalled back to v6.3 but not sure if that made any difference